# Custom template or class creation companies

Tags: templates

I am looking into creating a custom template or class for my business. We will be publishing monthly and quarterly reports focusing on economic conditions. Does anyone know any companies or consultants that might be able to create custom templates using our brand fonts, colors, logos etc?

I used Latex extensively in grad school and could maybe could have done this on my own a decade ago, but my skills are very rusty and I simply don't have the time.

Comment: TUG has a list of (self-reported) consultants: https://tug.org/consultants.html Youy might find a suitable source there.

Comment: I'm ready to accept the offer

Comment: @barbarabeeton I saw that list. Unfortunately it seems very out of date. Several sights are non functioning and several more have not seen any sort of updates in many years. Thank you for the link though.